# Exporting tables from db2/as400 to Windows db2

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

Hello everybody (this is my first question, be patient... And be patient for my english too...).

This is what I need: I have a db2 on as400 and i have to export some schemas (one or two) to a db2 database on Windowws. I already created the tables structures (exporting sql create statements), my problem is how to populate those tables with the data contained in as400 db

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a tool that will create SQL scripts to connect to DB2, FETCH and INSERT INTO your SQL Server database.  There may not be a simple solution because of relational constraints.

Comment: In fact that's what i did. I found no solution so I had to write it by myself, thank you for answering!